# SSH not working after Restoring Running-Config to a Replacement Cisco Router

Tags: networking, cisco

One of my Cisco routers died over the weekend, Cisco sent the replacement and I restored the the config using `copy tftp: running-config`.  Everything seems to work fine but I can no longer ssh into the router (I can telnet).  The connection is refused, so it isn't listening on port 22 it seems like.

I had previously backed up the config by just doing `ssh router 'show run' > backup_config` from my workstation.

So:

1. Is there anything wrong with my method of backup vs `copy running-config tftp:`?
2. I know I haven't given any debug information, but is there something typical I need to do to get ssh working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that your crypto keys may not have been backed up, running something like

```
router(config)# crypto key generate rsa
```

will enable `ssh`.

Comment: It will prompt you for the key length.  I suggest 1024 so you can support SSH v2.

Comment: Will this effect any IPSec site to site tunnels? (The one active one I have is currently up)

Comment: I don't think so, but...

Comment: Okay thanks mat, going to have to wait for a maintenance window to accept the answer :-P

Answer (score 1):

Does `transport input ssh` show under line vty 0 4?

It seems unlikely but there could be a really old IOS on there that doesn't support SSH.